# GooglePlacesAutocompleteとgoogle-map-reactを共存させる方法

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

#### 前提・実現したいこと

現在React.jsを用いて投稿型webアプリを制作しています。
メインのコードは書き終えたのですが１箇所だけwarningが解決しないため、是非皆さんの知恵を貸していただきたいです。
エラーは以下の通りです。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
Aborted attempt to load Google Maps JS with @googlemaps/js-api-loader.This may result in undesirable behavior as script parameters may not match.
```

#### 該当のソースコード

Map.js

```
import GoogleMapReact from "google-map-react";
...
//住所から地名を取得
  const Geocoding = useCallback(() => {
    Geocode.setApiKey("AIzaSyDUDTHfWX33hew2WbRittJIKhHfVWgz5dY");
    Geocode.fromAddress(prop.address).then(
      (response) => {
        const { lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;
        setSpotLat(lat);
        setSpotLng(lng);
        console.log(lat, lng);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error(error);
      }
    );
  }, [prop.address]);
  useEffect(() => {
    Geocoding();
  }, [Geocoding]);
...
    <GoogleMapReact
        bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: "AIzaSyDUDTHfWX33hew2WbRittJIKhHfVWgz5dY" }}
        center={{
          lat: spotLat,
          lng: spotLng,
        }}
        defaultZoom={16}
        yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals
      >
```

Map.js

```
import GooglePlacesAutocomplete from "react-google-places-autocomplete";
...
                      <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
                        apiKey="AIzaSyDUDTHfWX33hew2WbRittJIKhHfVWgz5dY"
                        selectProps={{
                          value: courseSpotAddress,
                          onChange: setcourseSpotAddress,
                          placeholder: "名前を打ち込んでください（例　神戸駅）",
                        }}
                        apiOptions={{ language: "jp", region: "jp" }}
                        menuContainerStyle={{ zIndex: 999 }}
                        //style={styles.tweet_input}
                        menuPortalTarget={document.body}
                        menuPosition={"fixed"}
                      />
```

#### 他サイト様での質問

teratailにて同様の質問をしています。
https://teratail.com/questions/343951

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/343951) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: 了解しました。質問サイト初心者なので知らなかったです。ありがとうございます。